# Find adjoint operator

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)$. Denote by $V$ the subspace of finite linear combinations of the basis-vectors. Define $T$ on $\mathcal{H}$ with $D(T) = V$ by $$T\left(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j e_j\right) = \sum_{j=1}^n c_j e_1$$

I want to find the adjoint operator $T^*$ and the closure of $G(T)$ the graph.

My problem is this: So for the first part. $\mathcal{H}^* = B(\mathcal{H}, \mathbb{C})$, $$D(T^*) =  \left\{y^*\in \mathcal{H}^*: |y^*(Tx)|\leq C_{y^*}\left\|x\right\|_{\mathcal{H}}, x\in V
 \right\}$$

(This is what i got from my definitions: So $D(T^*)$ consists of functionals for which the map $x\mapsto y^*(Tx)$ is continuous for all $x\in V$)

The adjoint transformation is defined by $$T^*y^* = x^* $$ for which $y^*(Tx)= x^*(x)$ for all $x\in V$. So then I first need to determine which functionals $y^*$ are in $D(T^*)$ right? But i havent been given a norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{\mathcal{H}}$...could someone help me out?

Comment: It is most likely $\sum c_j e_1$.

Comment: Yes, but someone edited it. :P Nvm...thought I wrote it down right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing down the matrix of $T$, you find algebraically
$$
T^*:\sum_{n\geq 1} x_ne_n\longmapsto x_1\sum_{n\geq 1}e_n.
$$
But $\sum_{n\geq 1}e_n$ does not converge in $H$, so the domain of $T^*$ is $\{x\;;\; x_1=0\}$ and $T^*=0$.

Now let us do this less casually.
Check that the functional 
$$
y\longmapsto (x,Ty)=\overline{x_1}\sum_{n\geq 0}y_j
$$
is bounded if and only if $x_1=0$ (otherwise, consider the partial sums of the harmonic series). It follows that 
$$
D(T^*)=e_1^\perp=\{x\;;\; x_1=0\}.
$$
Now 
$$
(x,Ty)=0\qquad \forall y\in V\quad\forall x\in e_1^\perp.
$$
So
$$
T^*=0.
$$

The graph of $T$ is
$$
G(T)=\{(x,\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}x_n\right)e_1)\;;\; x\in V\}.
$$
One sees that
$$
G(T)^\perp=\{0\}\times e_1^\perp
$$
hence
$$ 
\overline{G(T)}=G(T)^{\perp\perp}=H\times \mbox{Span} e_1.
$$

Comment: There's something i dont quite understand though. Cause an adjoint sends maps to maps right? Here it is a map on $\mathcal{H}$. Istead of a map on $B(\mathcal{H},\mathbb{C})$ ? In linear algebra I know we talk about adjoint matrices this way...but it confuses me a little.

Comment: I used the usual isometric identification $B(H,\mathbb{C})\simeq H$ vie Riesz representtation theorem. When working with a Hilbert space, one (almost) always does that because it makes everything much easier to write. A functional is just $(x,\cdot)$, which has norm $\|x\|$. So it is identified with $x$.